# iOS alternative for Android:nextFocusUp/nextFocusDown/

Tags: ios, focus, accessibility

Is there a way in Objective C to determine the next focusable textfield when directional input methods (like trackball, keyboard, ...) are used?

It should be similar to Android's nextFocusUp, nextFocusDown, nextFocuLeft, nextFocusRight

Answer (score 0):

Your textfields are ordered by a tag in their parent view.

You could set the tags for all your textfields and then find them using `[view viewWithTag:tag]`:

```
NSInteger tag = [currentTextField tag] + 1; // + 1 for next, - 1 for prev

UITextField nextField = [currentTextField.superview viewWithTag:tag];
if(nextField){
    [nextField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: how can i combine this with directional pads, for example a trackball? do i have to implement a listener for that?

Comment: Yes you will need some kind of direction input. I would use event listener and then transform incoming events to required tags